# Como acessar índices de trás pra frente dentro de uma lista?

Tags: python, lista, índices

Estou pegando as notas que formam as tríades dos acordes maiores. Para isso, criei uma lista com todas as notas possíveis, e de acordo com o acorde digitado eu varro a lista a procura da primeira maior, terça maior e quinta justa, com o seguinte cálculo:

```
notas = ['C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G', 'G#', 'A', 'A#', 'B']
triade = []
acorde = str(input('Acorde desejado: '))
if len(acorde) == 1:  # se for um acorde maior sem sétima
    for i, nota in enumerate(notas):
        if nota == acorde:
            triade.append(nota)  # 1º maior
        elif i == notas.index(acorde) + 4:
            triade.append(nota)  # 3º maior
        elif i == notas.index(acorde) + 7:
            triade.append(nota)  # 5º justa

print(triade)
```

O problema é que se eu pegar qualquer acorde a partir de `F`, o cálculo vai passar do limite da lista e vai dar erro. Pra corrigir isso, eu poderia simplesmente repetir os valores dentro dela de novo que daria certo, mas me surgiu uma curiosidade; posso reordenar a lista a partir do acorde digitado?

**Ex: Acorde desejado: A**

**notas = ['A', 'A#', 'B', 'C', 'C#'...]**

Eu poderia também por um `if` caso chegue no `i == 11`, pra reiniciar a contagem, ou existe um cálculo que possa fazer isso sem uma condicional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se sua intenção é iterar ciclicamente os índices de uma lista pela direita, ou seja fazer que quando o índice pesquisado exceder o comprimento da lista volte ao início, basta obter o resto da divisão inteira entre o índice e o comprimento da lista usando operador [`%`(Operador Resto)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#module-operator):

```
notas = ['C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G', 'G#', 'A', 'A#', 'B']
triade = []
acorde = input('Acorde desejado: ').upper() #o retorno input já uma string
if len(acorde) == 1:  # se for um acorde maior sem sétima
    for i, nota in enumerate(notas):
        if nota == acorde:
            triade.append(nota)  # 1º maior
        elif i == (notas.index(acorde) + 4) % len(notas):
            triade.append(nota)  # 3º maior
        elif i == (notas.index(acorde) + 7) % len(notas):
            triade.append(nota)  # 5º justa

print(triade)
```

Teste no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@RonaldoVasques/notas)

Answer (score 3):

Se você só quer pegar 3 elementos específicos da lista de notas, não precisa fazer um *loop* por toda a lista. Basta pegar o índice do elemento digitado e a partir dele calcular os demais, e depois você cria outra lista só com esses índices:

```
if len(acorde) == 1:
    try:
        i = notas.index(acorde)
        triade = [ notas[i], notas[(i + 4) % len(notas)], notas[(i + 7) % len(notas)] ]
    except ValueError:
        print(f'{acorde} não é um acorde válido')
```

O detalhe é que [segundo a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) o método `index` lança um [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) caso o elemento não exista na lista, então incluí essa verificação.

Outro detalhe é que só é preciso chamar `index` uma vez, e a partir do resultado dele calculamos os demais índices (4 e 7 posições à frente, usando o operador `%` para voltar ao início da lista se for o caso, conforme a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/454524/112052) já explicou).

Assim fica melhor porque cada chamada de `index` precisa percorrer a lista novamente, até encontrar o elemento em questão (ou seja, da forma que você tinha feito, a lista é percorrida várias vezes, sem necessidade). Como o elemento é o mesmo durante todo o *loop* e a lista não é modificada, só precisa chamar `index` uma vez. E como eu só quero posições específicas a partir deste índice, não precisa percorrer toda a lista até encontrar essas posições: pegue-as diretamente e pronto.

<sup>*Ao percorrer a lista várias vezes sem necessidade, você está criando uma variação do chamado [Shlemiel the painter's algorithm](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/).*</sup>

---

A diferença é que nem sempre a ordem da lista `triade` será a mesma do seu código. Por exemplo, se o acorde digitado for `'A'`, a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/454524/112052) tem como resultado a lista `['C#', 'E', 'A']`, já o código acima tem como resultado a lista `['A', 'C#', 'E']`.

Isso porque, como o `A` está mais próximo do final da lista e as posições seguintes estão no começo, o *loop* encontra o `C#` e o `E` antes.

Se quer manter a mesma ordem do seu *loop* original, basta ordenar os índices antes de obter a lista:

```
if len(acorde) == 1:
    try:
        i = notas.index(acorde)
        indices = sorted([ i, (i + 4) % len(notas), (i + 7) % len(notas) ])
        triade = list(map(lambda idx: notas[idx], indices))
    except ValueError:
        print(f'{acorde} não é um acorde válido')
```

Primeiro eu uso [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) para ordenar os índices (a posição do acorde, e 4 e 7 posições à frente). Depois eu mapeio cada posição para o respectivo elemento da lista de notas.

Em vez de usar [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), outra forma de criar a lista `triade` a partir dos índices é usar uma [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](/q/192343/112052):

```
if len(acorde) == 1:
    try:
        i = notas.index(acorde)
        indices = sorted([ i, (i + 4) % len(notas), (i + 7) % len(notas) ])
        triade = [ notas[idx] for idx in indices ] # usar list comprehension em vez de list(map(etc...))
    except ValueError:
        print(f'{acorde} não é um acorde válido')
```

Answer (score 2):

Pensei numa solução bastante simples, consistente na criação de uma nova lista, com a reordenação das notas a partir do acorde informado pelo usuário, por meio do fatiamento da lista original:

```
notas = ['C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G', 'G#', 'A', 'A#', 'B']
triade = []
acorde = str(input('Acorde desejado: '))
if len(acorde) == 1:  # se for um acorde maior sem sétima
    notas_ordenadas = notas[notas.index(acorde):] + notas[:notas.index(acorde)] # reordena as notas a partir do acorde escolhido
    triade = [notas_ordenadas[0], notas_ordenadas[4], notas_ordenadas[7]]

print(triade)
```

Answer (score 1):

No início da pergunta, nos foi passada uma `lista`, chamada de `notas`, ou seja...

```
notas = ['C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G', 'G#', 'A', 'A#', 'B']
```

Esta lista nada mais é do que a [escala cromática](https://www.descomplicandoamusica.com/escala-cromatica/) de `Dó`. Nesta situação não temos `modos` (modo maior ou menor).

Como é evidente, nesta lista, além das notas naturais `(C, D, E, F, G, A, B)`, temos também as notas acidentadas `(C#, D#, F#, G#, A#)`, que também podemos chamar de notas `sustenizadas`.

Estas notas, não estão dentro da lista por acaso. Pois, elas também `podem formar` acordes. Neste caso, são os acordes sustenidos.

No caso de formação de acordes, existem vários [tipos](https://aprendateclado.com/mundo-dos-acordes/). Para fins de agilidade, neste post, vou me deter apenas no acorde **Maior**. Pois - em sua forma mais básica - é formado por apenas **três notas** e **dois intervalos**.

As [notas](https://www.descomplicandoamusica.com/graus-tonais-supertonica-mediante-superdominante-e-sensivel/) serão:

1. **Tônica**: 1º grau da escala;
2. **Mediante**: 3º grau da escala;
3. **Dominante**: 5º grau da escala.

E os intervalos serão:

1. **Terça maior**: 4 semitons entre a tônica e a mediante;
2. **Quinta justa**: 7 semitons entre a tônica e a dominante.

**Observação:** Os intervalos serão sempre contados a partir da **tônica**.

Adotando a tônica como sendo o **baixo** do acorde, ou seja, posicionando a tônica como sendo a nota mais grave do acorde (1ª nota do acorde), podemos implementar o seguinte script.

```
notas = ['C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G', 'G#', 'A', 'A#', 'B']

while (baixo := input('Baixo do acorde desejado: ').upper()) not in notas:
    print('Valor INVÁLIDO!')

triade = [notas[(notas.index(baixo) + i) % 12] for i in (0, 4, 7)]

print(f'{baixo}M:', *triade)
```

Este script solicita o **baixo** do acorde desejado. Em seguida, ele verifica se o baixo digitado pelo usuário é, de fato, válido, isto é, verifica se o baixo digitado pelo usuário, de fato, se encontra na lista **notas**. Enquanto o valor digitado for inválido, o script exibirá uma mensagem de erro e solicitará novamente o baixo do acorde. Caso o valor digitado seja válido, o programa avançará sua execução.

Na próxima faze, o script montará o acorde desejado com o auxílio de **[list comprehensio](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions)**.

Observe que nesta etapa o bloco **for** percorre a tupla **(0, 4, 7)**. Esta tupla é formada pelo tamanho dos respectivos intervalos.

O **0**, corresponde ao intervalo nulo. O valor **4** corresponde ao intervalo de **terça maior** e o valor **7**, corresponde ao intervalo de **quinta justa**.

Para cada iteração do laço é montada a respectiva nota desejada, obtendo-se com o auxílio do seguinte código:

```
notas[(notas.index(baixo) + i) % 12]
```

A função deste código é basicamente identificar a nota, cujo índice do baixo, se encontra na lista **notas**. E, para isso, é calculado o **RESTO** da divisão real entre a soma de **(notas.index(baixo)** com o respectivo **referido intervalo i** e o valor **12**. O valor **12** corresponde ao tamanho da lista **notas**.

Uma vez montado o acorde o mesmo será exibido utilizando o seguinte formato:

```
print(f'{baixo}M:', *triade)
```

Este formato exibe o nome do **baixo** juntamente com a designação de maior **(M)**, seguido dois pontos "**:**" e seguido pelo desempacotamento da tríade **(*triade)**.

**Testando o código:**

Ao executar o código e digitássemos o valor...

```
A
```

...e pressionarmos <kbd>Enter</kbd>, obteremos como resultado:

```
AM: A C# E
```

Desta forma, recebemos como resultado o **nome** do acorde, juntamente com seu **modo**, juntamente com as **notas** de formação do referido acorde.